# Does Grindclock's counter reset when it's activated?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When a player taps the [Grindclock](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Grindclock) ability to pull X cards from a player's library and place them in the graveyard, does the counter reset?

Comment: And this was a bad question why?

Comment: This question can basically be answered by "just do what the card says", so some people might see it as a lack of trying.

Comment: It was a question that came up during play and no one knew the answer.  Since there are cards that don't always act like what they tell you to do, it seemed relevant. @ikegami responded in the apporpraiet manner.  Whomever voted it down did not.

Comment: It's a poor question because it is uninteresting and poorly considered. What about the ability would remove the counters? Activating an ability? Tapping? Setting X? Targeting? Removing cards from a library? Putting cards in a graveyard? There's absolutely no reason to believe it would remove counters except that someone wants it to do so. Sure, you can ask for confirmation and we'll answer you, but it's still a poor question.

Comment: Actually, balance of card power in the game would suggest it not maintain its' counter.

Comment: Totally unfounded in anything but feelings.

Comment: It is clearly not totally unfounded since they have removed cords from play in play formats for that very reason.  As to playing a card as it says to be played, that can be a bit baffling to people.  Consider: http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ice Cauldron

Comment: @StephenWinburn If you added a *good* reason for why you think the counters would be lost, I would retract my downvote. *"It seems overpowered."* is a bad reason. *"Cards in general are not what they appear."* is also a bad reason. I'm left wondering how you play Magic if you are this cautious of every card.

Comment: @StephenWinburn Ice Cauldron still does exactly what it says (or at least exactly what the oracle text says). It may be a little hard to figure out at first, but it's not ambiguous, and neither is Grindclock.

Comment: @StephenWinburn: "there are cards that don't always act like what they tell you to do" — Name one.

Comment: It seems the counter builds up as a costs that should be expended and rebuilt.  This is logical.  The alternative is not.  Otherwise it would imbalance play.  Examples of cards not reprinted due to causing power imbalances include the Power of Nine and Black Lotus. The latter is also an artifact, and suffers the same possibility for defeat during play.

Comment: @StephenWinburn But the counters **don't** build up as a cost. It's a card that slowly gets more powerful over the course of the game. It's not imbalanced because it's pretty slow, and mill is hard to win with.

Comment: Here is a article (research paper) on such imbalances of power that addresses magic as one of its focuses.

Comment: I'd suggest moving the discussion of power imbalances to the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49/board-and-card-games), because it is only tangentially related to the question. The important question in these comments is what made you **expect** that the card did not behave as printed. And, relatedly, jwodder's question.

Comment: @StephenWinburn Actually, while the power 9 are certainly overpowered, the real reason they are not reprinted is due to their being on the reserved list. If you're looking for an example of a card that won't be reprinted --only-- for power level reasons, I would consider Jace the Mind Sculptor as your posterboy. To quote Mark Rosewater "Standard has never been at a power level where Jace, the Mind Sculptor was not over powered. (Well, maybe Standard with Urza’s Saga block.)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In MTG, counters are physical markers that are counted, added and removed; they are not abstractions that store a number that can be manipulated. As such, it makes no sense to talk about *resetting* a counter; you want to know if the counters are *removed*.

Nothing instructs you to remove the the counters, so you do not remove them. Just like attacking doesn't remove +1/+1 counters, using Grindclock's ability does not remove charge counters.

[Things that remove counters](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/18413/2880).

Answer (score 2):

**The counters on Grindclock do not reset.** In fact, "Reset" is not a special keyword that means anything to a Magic player. The short answer is that if nothing says to remove counters, they don't get removed. The long answer is that they remain until one of two things happen:

- An effect removes the counters
- The object upon which the counters were placed cease to exist

An example of the first bullet is [Power Conduit](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Power%20Conduit), which has an activated ability that removes counters. Coincidentally, it creates counters that are interchangeable with those generated by Grindclock.

An example of the second bullet would be if I cast [Naturalize](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Naturalize) on your Grindclock. Your Grindclock would be destroyed. Any counters on it cease to exist. This is not the same as "removing" counters.

Comment: By the way, you mentioned a downvoter earlier... When I vote, I vote on the post's merits. It wasn't me; the small error is not enough to merit a downvote.

Comment: @Ikegami I think it's fair to say Rainbolt isn't implying that. The question is "Does this card get its counters reset?" This answer says "No it doesn't." It then goes on to say that nothing else does except for when it says so, which is about as general a statement as one would expect. If there's a general implication here that other cards reset their counters, that's accurate, because some other cards do. Except they say so, as this answer goes on to say.

Comment: @ikegami So do you have a suggestion for improvement, as is the point of.comments?

Comment: @ikegami Sounds ok. That plus "and there's no such thing as counters resetting" I guess?